# Shared session between Moodle 2.2 and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, moodle

I need to share the session between a Ruby on Rails app and a Moodle 2.2 instance. Namely, the web app and Moodle users use the same LDAP authentication server. What I need is that the user only authenticate once in one of the two apps and that session can be used by the other app.

Does anyone have any ideas that can help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are going to have to implement some type of Singe Sign On (SSO) to accomplish this. Check out either http://www.jasig.org/cas or http://shibboleth.net/.